# Make Material Floating Label always Float

Tags: jquery, css, class, materialize

I have a piece of code here that I'm sure everyone is also aware and here it is

```
<input id="fspcode" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="fspcode" required class="input-material font1">
<label for="fspcode" class="label-material font1">Code :</label>
```

and the output of that is this

**Floating Label on the Textbox**

[image]

It is the famous class of floating label when the mouse focuses on the textbox.

My problem now is this. This is what happens when I assign value programmatically

**Label on the top of value**

[image]

My question is how can I make it always go up? as in everytime so I dont have to worry even if i put,assign or remove a value on the textbox still it will go up.

any possible help?

Comment: Try setting the value after the page load

Comment: i try that but it only works one time but after initiating it the remove the value then added again still the class doesnt work